# IPad Playground Has Different View.Frame

Tags: swift, xcode, ipad, swift-playground, ipad-playgrounds

I am trying to show this simple ViewController in iPad Playgrounds with this code:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupViews()
}

func setupViews() {
    let view1 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width/2, height: 100))
    view1.backgroundColor = .red
    view.addSubview(view1)
}
}
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

You can see that, even though it says view.frame.width/2 for the frame of View1, the view still looks like this:

[image]

What is wrong? Thank you.

Comment: If you drag the edge of the preview half of the screen all the way to the left—so that you get a full screen preview—does the red view still cover the full width? I suspect that the problem is that the `MyViewController` live view is too large to fit the preview and thus appear to crop to the preview size.

Comment: It's kind of weird, if I drag it out all of the way, if I drag it out all the way, it covers around 60% of the width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Here’s how to get it to work]

This is the solution I used which got it to work. In Swift Playgrounds, the layout is created in the `viewDidLayoutSubview` method so all frames should be created there.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your preferred size after you init your ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class VC: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupViews()
    }

    func setupViews() {
        let view1 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width/2, height: 100))
        view1.backgroundColor = .red
        view.addSubview(view1)
    }
}

let vc = VC()
vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 768, height: 1024)

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vc
```

[Playground with preferredContentSize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oC2XP.png)

[Playground without preferredContentSize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QP34.png)

Comment: Didn’t work for me. Keep in mind that I’m running on an iPad. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @NikolasIoannou, that's frustrating.  I just pulled out my iPad version and it looks like the preview on the right isn't doing the correct thing (I wonder if there's a way to make the liveView fullscreen).  If you tap the little square under your `addSubview(_:)` call, it looks like it _should_ be working correctly https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8k3C.png

Comment: Yes, that is odd. I'll have to look into that.